# Verifying that ODE integration generates Theoretical Stationary distribution

Tags: ode, statistics, probability

I am trying to simulate an ODE, like $ \dot{x} = \xi(x) $ that should have a stationary distribution (a la Stat Mech). Assuming that my ODE algorithm generates time samples of my system state $ x $ like $ x^{(0)}, ..., x^{(t)}, x^{(t+1)}, ..., x^{(n)} $, I would like to verify that the samples generated from the ODE numerically approximately match the theoretical distribution (or at least in metrics like entropy/KL Divergence they match).

I thought about running Monte Carlo and the ODE and trying to compare the generated results, but I don't know how to compare the samples generated as they are generated in a high dimensional phase space. Normally (low dimensions), I would use binning and compute KL divergence.

*My motivation is to further convince myself that the results from ["On the classical statistical mechanics of non-Hamiltonian systems" by Tuckerman](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/epl/i1999-00139-0/meta) are real.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, your type of question would be called a "multivariate goodness of fit test". If $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is the $n$-dimensional CDF for the theoretical distribution, and the random variables $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ are a sample from your ODE, then
$$ Z_1 = F(X_1), \quad Z_2 = F(X_2\mid X_1), \quad\cdots\quad Z_n = F(X_n\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}) $$
are random variables that are uniformly independently distributed in the unit cube $[0,1]^n$. This is  [Rosenblatt's transform](https://doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177729394), similar to the [probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform).

So if your system is ergodic and enough time passes between the ODE samples for them to be independent, you can just test that the vectors $z^{(0)},\ldots,z^{(n)}$ are u.i.d. on the unit cube. This in turn can be done, for example, by splitting the cube into bins and using the chi-square test.

Comment: Amazing idea. Never thought of that. Some [existing Python tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268632/goodness-of-fit-tests-in-scipy) for reference sake. The [Anderson-Darling test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.anderson.html#scipy.stats.anderson), the [k-sample A-D test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp.html#scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp), and the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html)